# mySQL - how to switch column values- 'short' to 'long' and 'long' to 'short'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database, and in one the tables I need change the values of a column, due to a mix up with another developer. I have table called `credits`, and a column called `credit_type`.

`credit_type` has 2 values `long` and `short`.

How can I replace all the values that are `long` to read `short`, and all the values that are `short` to read `long`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update credits set credit_type = 'interim' where credit_type = 'long';
update credits set credit_type = 'long' where credit_type = 'short';
update credits set credit_type = 'short' where credit_type = 'interim';
```

Wrap it all in a transaction for full reliability.